# How can I skip my attack?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

Is there anyway to skip/delay a characters turn in battle?

The scenario:
It is Butter's turn and he is out of pp. His only other attack is melee. 
The only enemy he can attack is in a riposte stance and I do not want to take damage from attacking him with my hammer..

I want to skip his turn and then attack with the main character who happens to have a bow equip. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no option to skip an attack.

What you *can* do is either use a Power Potion and then a spell (items are a 'free' action, and there's really no point in hoarding consumables), or use the 'Switch Buddy' command to swap in a different team member with a ranged attack, such as Kenny.

Alternately, just eat the Riposte. Honestly, they usually don't do that much damage. Butters can handle it.

Comment: It looks like it is possible to block the Riposte, so attack and block?

Comment: A comment for future readers that might face a different dilemma, you can choose to attack but not press any buttons for the QTE to effectively void any damage. This won't help for avoiding ripostes but will help if you don't want to do any damage!